# Relatively positioned content not stacking vertically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to stack these elements so that they lie on top of one another, but they end up squishing horizontally instead. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```css
    .content-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .content-box {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 5vh 5vw;
      font-family: "Roboto";
      color: #676767;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 60vw;
      position: relative;
      z-index:10;
      margin: 1vh
    }
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">
            <span class="title"> Stats </span>
            <br>
            <div class="sep"></div>
            <p> Lorem ipsum 1 </p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="content-box">
            <span class="title"> Stats </span>
            <br>
            <div class="sep"></div>
            <p> Lorem ipsum 2 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "I am trying to stack these elements so that they lie on top of one another,"? Dint get you...

Answer (score 0):

Use flex boxes instead. [`flex direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

```css
.box-list {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="box-list">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-direction: column;` to the wrapper:

```css
.content-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .content-box {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 5vh 5vw;
      font-family: "Roboto";
      color: #676767;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 60vw;
      position: relative;
      z-index:10;
      margin: 1vh
    }
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-box">
            <span class="title"> Stats </span>
            <br>
            <div class="sep"></div>
            <p> Lorem ipsum 1 </p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="content-box">
            <span class="title"> Stats </span>
            <br>
            <div class="sep"></div>
            <p> Lorem ipsum 2 </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```